# How to count the number of occurrences of one variable that are shared between levels of another variable

Tags: r, count

I have data that looks like

```
id      camera
angelina    cam03
angelina    cam03
angelina    cam03
angelina    cam03
angelina    cam03
angelina    cam03
angelina    cam03
angelina    cam03
angelina    cam03
angelina    cam03
angelina    cam03
angelina    cam22
barry   cam03
barry   cam03
barry   cam03
barry   cam03
barry   cam03
barry   cam03
barry   cam03
barry   cam03
barry   cam03
barry   cam03
barry   cam22
barry   cam22
barry   cam22
barry   cam22
barry   cam22
barry   cam15
barry   cam25
```

So each individual is recorded in each camera that it is captured in, I want to know how many individuals are seen in each pair of cameras, therefore for cameraa 1 and 2, how many indivduals are recorded in both, in the example above, only individual A is seen in both cameras 1 and 2, for cameras 1 and 3, individual B and E is seen in them both, so the desired result I would like would be a table like

```
    0001  0002  0003
0001 -     1      2
0002  1    -      0
0003  2    0      -
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could show me the code for this please in R

Comment: First thing is how much Cameras do you have?

Comment: `crossprod(table(mydf))`?

Comment: that ^...and set the `diag` to NA and you are good to go

Comment: I have twentyone cmeras

Comment: Hi heres is a portion of the real data,

Comment: @alexk in the first example data you had no duplicate camera per individual. In your real data you do, that is why the proposed answer don't work as it is and why it is important to put a **representative** example of your real case. A slight modification of the `crossprod` answer should do (you can also have a look at my answer)

Answer (score 3):

`crossprod` should do it for this:

```
crossprod(table(mydf))
#       Camera
# Camera 0001 0002 0003
#   0001    4    1    2
#   0002    1    1    0
#   0003    2    0    3
```

`diag` can be used to set the diagonal to zero or `NA` if required. You can do it all in one go with:

```
`diag<-`(crossprod(table(mydf)), 0)
#       Camera
# Camera 0001 0002 0003
#   0001    0    1    2
#   0002    1    0    0
#   0003    2    0    0
```

Sample data:

```
mydf <- data.frame(
    Individual = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "E", "E"),
    Camera = c("0001", "0002", "0001", "0003", "0001", "0003", "0001", "0003"))
```

**EDIT:**

In case of duplicated cameras for same individual, you can eliminate the duplicates prior to the `crossprod` call:

```
`diag<-`(crossprod(table(unique(mydf2))), 0)
       camera
#camera  cam03 cam15 cam22 cam25
  #cam03     0     1     2     1
  #cam15     1     0     1     1
  #cam22     2     1     0     1
  #cam25     1     1     1     0
```

Second data:

```
mydf2 <- structure(list(id = c("angelina", "angelina", "angelina", "angelina", 
"angelina", "angelina", "angelina", "angelina", "angelina", "angelina", 
"angelina", "angelina", "barry", "barry", "barry", "barry", "barry", 
"barry", "barry", "barry", "barry", "barry", "barry", "barry", 
"barry", "barry", "barry", "barry", "barry"), camera = c("cam03", 
"cam03", "cam03", "cam03", "cam03", "cam03", "cam03", "cam03", 
"cam03", "cam03", "cam03", "cam22", "cam03", "cam03", "cam03", 
"cam03", "cam03", "cam03", "cam03", "cam03", "cam03", "cam03", 
"cam22", "cam22", "cam22", "cam22", "cam22", "cam15", "cam25"
)), .Names = c("id", "camera"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-29L))
```

Comment: This produces a table that looks like what I want, but the values in it are incorrect

Comment: @alexk. "the values in it are incorrect" isn't exactly an error I can troubleshoot....

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1, I have added some of the real data to the question, I used your code excatly, and got numbers as high as in the 1000s, but there are only 300 ish rows in the data, so at any pair of cameras I would expect the most to be 20 or 30, maybe 50